# NSWindow events at kCGDesktopWindowLevel

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseevent, nswindow

I am trying to make an interactive desktop application that replaces the wallpaper image. It sounds like it is not possible to have an `NSWindow` at that level with events. According to all of the documentation I can find, a window needs to be at level -598 in order to allow views to accept such events, but the desktop level is -1000. Is there a way to get past this limitation (if there even is a limitation) with a light-weight API?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I am so embarrassed!

I printed the value of kCGDesktopWindowLevel and it turned out to be -2147483623. When I set the level of the window to -1000 it started to work perfectly.

Comment: That doesn't actually "work" since the window will be above the desktop icons